# How to use HMM model for audio segmentation

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, signal-processing, hidden-markov-models

I am trying to perform audio segmentation of signals using HMM/GMM model. I have applied the model but unable to figure out how the output has to be used on my dataset for further feature extraction.

Tried running this with modifications

```py
#AUDIO SEGMENTATION USING HMM

from pyAudioAnalysis import audioSegmentation as aS
aS.train_hmm_from_directory('C:/Users/va/Downloads/archive (1)/set_a', "hmmTemp2", 1.0, 1.0)
aS.hmm_segmentation('data/scottish.wav', 'data/hmmRadioSM', True, 'data/scottish.segments')
```

but as.hmm_segmentation gives error and not running fine.

Also, tried

```py
from hmmlearn import hmm

samplerate,data = wavfile.read('C:/Users/va/Downloads/archive (1)/set_a/artifact__201012172012.wav')
model = hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=3, covariance_type="full").fit(X_dataA)
X, Z = model.sample(100)
```

Cannot figure out how to further make use of it on my data

Comment: Vibhuti, welcome to the stackoverflow. To make your question more clear and increase the chances of answering, please format your code as desribed in [https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), add error message you encountered and describe, how have you tried to address the issue.

Comment: vibhuti can you share the error you are getting, i am unable to understand what problem you are actually facing regarding hmm_segmentation, i have been able to do it easily.